# Generated inputs get values and add them into a url params

Tags: jquery, url, input

I have two select fields which generate `<input>` fields according to the result of select 1 + select 2.

Like this :

```
jQuery(function($)
{
        $('select[name="nb_adultes"], select[name="nb_enfants"]').change(function()
        {
                var total_a = parseInt($('select[name="nb_adultes"]').val());
                var total_e = parseInt($('select[name="nb_enfants"]').val());

                if (total_a + total_e > 10)
                {
                        alert("La somme du nombre d'adultes et d'enfants ne doit pas dépasser 10");
                }
                else
                {
                        $("#input_appended").empty();

                        for(var j=0; j < total_a; j++) 
                        $("#input_appended").append('<label for="date_naissance">Date de naissance Adulte</label><input type="text" name="date_naissance_a_'+j+'"/><br />');

                        for(var k=0; k < total_e; k++) 
                        $("#input_appended").append('<label for="date_naissance">Date de naissance Enfant</label><input type="text" name="date_naissance_e_'+j+'"/><br />');
                }
        });
});
```

I need to retrieve the VALUE of each input fields generated AND save them for integrating into a url param :

Example :

Select field 1 show number "2" and Select field 2 show number "1" so I have 3 input fields, I need this :

```
var select_1-1 = input VAL1
var select_1-2 = input VAL2
var select_2-1 = input VAL3

var url = "http://www.url.com/page.php?select_1-1=VAL1&select_1-2=VAL2&select_2-1=VAL3"
```

Any help would be very very appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There's no HTML, so you'll have to figure out selectors yourself.

```
var VAL1 = $(select_1-1).val();
var VAL2 = $(select_1-2).val();
var VAL3 = $(select_2-1).val();

var url = "http://www.url.com/page.php?select_1-1="+VAL1+"&select_1-2="+VAL2+"&select_2-1="+VAL3;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but that's not what I want, I want to retrieve the VAL of generated input then put them in my url

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of the inputs and store them in variables do:

```
var VAL1 = $(select_1-1).val();
var VAL2 = $(select_1-2).val();
var VAL3 = $(select_2-1).val();
```

Then you can put them together in another variable called myurl like:

```
var myurl = "http://www.url.com/page.php?select_1-1="+
VAL1+
"&select_1-2="+
VAL2+"&select_2-1="+
VAL3;
```

Then if you want to open in a new window that myurl use:

```
window.open( myurl, '_blank' )
```

if instead you want to just add the myurl to your url and not refresh the page use:

```
var myurl = "/page.php?select_1-1="+
    VAL1+
    "&select_1-2="+
    VAL2+"&select_2-1="+
    VAL3;
window.history.pushState('', "Title", myurl);
```